# Problem with connecting with remote database

Tags: server, 22.04, apache2, mysql, cluster

Hello there I have a question about connecting my website with my database on another server on the same network. My database uses a cluster-based system with MariaDB and my website uses apache2. I thought I could connect it with phpmyadmin but I can't find it. could you guys help me? all my servers are on ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? `I can't find it` is not a problem description.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: If the database is clustered and you're having difficulty connecting, I would guess that someone else set up that cluster. If so, then you may want to ask them whether your account is permitted to connect remotely and if it has the necessary permissions for the database(s) required 